# Creating a channel (or entries) using a similar channel

Tags: templating, entries, structure, image, navigation

I am currently trying to  make a channel called "classmates" similar to a  channel that is called "News".  I have this working beautifully, but I am not sure how to set a different template for ClassMates. Any help?

Answer (score 1):

You define the template to load for a channel's URL for each site in the site settings on the section settings page. See the screenshot below:

[image: Screenshot of Craft's section settings showing the URI format and template settings]

In the table at the bottom, you can set a URL format for each site (in the screenshot, there's only one site). Next to the URL, you can specify the template to render for that URL. In this example, the URL `news/{slug}` will render with the template `entries/news.twig` in your `templates/` folder.